# react-flow-renderer and react-beautiful-dnd: zoom issue that occurs when the zoom level is less than 100%

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd, react-flow

"I am using React Flow Renderer and React Beautiful Dnd to drag elements. When I drag an element, it is directly under the mouse cursor when the zoom level is 100%. However, when I decrease the zoom level below 100%, there is a distance between the mouse cursor and the dragged element. This distance increases as I further decrease the zoom level."

Example Video: https://www.loom.com/share/6f51c598ac0a4121ab3e2b0d7f0f8496